# Understanding groovy symantics?

Tags: groovy

I am trying to understand semantics of a particular groovy syntax.

```
def c = Account.createCriteria()

def results = c.list {
    like("holderFirstName", "Fred%")
    and {
        between("balance", 500, 1000)
        eq("branch", "London")
    }
    maxResults(10)
    order("holderLastName", "desc")
}
```

Is the {content} after c.list a closure. So, that can we understand that c.list method takes in a closure as parameter? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. List takes a closure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right

```
c.list
```

Takes a closure as a parameter